# How can I change my program by using a summing statement instead?

Tags: c++, for-loop, sum

My c++ assignment was to write a program to display the population estimate of each of the countries (Mexico and the US) by year, from 1985 to present. Round the population to the nearest whole number and display the information in three columns. After doing that, I was to modify the program for it to display the same information up to when Mexico's population exceeds the US population. I did the program correctly, when I ran it it gave me the correct information and all but my professor gave me 0 credit because he wants me to not use the POW function but a summing statement, I don't know how I can do that, it sounds more complicated to me. This is the program I wrote by the way I just don't know how to change it by using the summing statement:

```
//Program to compute when Mexico's pop exceeds the US pop
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Years;
    double UsPop, MxPop;
    cout<<setw(7)<<"Year"<<setw(13)<<"US Pop"<<setw(13)<<"Mex Pop"<<endl;
    cout<<setprecision(0)<<fixed;
    for(Years=1985;Years<=2014;Years++)
    {
        UsPop=243000000.0*(pow(1.007,(Years-1984)));
        MxPop=78000000*pow(1.033,(Years-1984));
        cout<<setw(7)<<Years<<setw(13)<<UsPop<<setw(13)<<MxPop<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "summing statement"? Is it a calculation that uses "+", or a calculation that uses "+" and no other operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "Summing statement", since it doesn't look like your problem needs a "+" operation.

In any case you don't have to use `pow`, you can just overwrite the US and Mex population number at each iteration that you just multiply using the indicator.

Below an example:

```
int main()
{
    int Years;
    double UsPop=243000000.0;
    double MxPop=78000000;
    cout<<setw(7)<<"Year"<<setw(13)<<"US Pop"<<setw(13)<<"Mex Pop"<<endl;
    cout<<setprecision(0)<<fixed;
    double usIndicator = 1.007;
    double mexIndicator = 1.033;

    for(Years=1985;Years<=2014;Years++)
    {
        UsPop=UsPop*usIndicator;
        MxPop=MxPop*mexIndicator;
        cout<<setw(7)<<Years<<setw(13)<<UsPop<<setw(13)<<MxPop<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your professor want you to write your own Pow function instead of using the one in Math library ? You can try to replace your :

```
for(Years=1985;Years<=2014;Years++)
{
    UsPop=243000000.0*(pow(1.007,(Years-1984)));
    MxPop=78000000*pow(1.033,(Years-1984));
    cout<<setw(7)<<Years<<setw(13)<<UsPop<<setw(13)<<MxPop<<endl;
}
```

to

```
for (Years = 1985; Years <= 2014; Years++)
{
             UsPop = 243000000.0 * (myPow((Years - 1985), 1.007));
             MxPop = 78000000 * (myPow((Years - 1985), 1.033));
}
```

Your Pow function will be something like :

```
    double myPow(double flag, double number)
    {
        double pow = number;
        //You can edit my formula to match "summing statement" as  your professor require .
        for (int i = 0; i < flag; i++)
        {
            pow *= number; //If I'm not mistaken, you should split it up to "Plus" then you will get your "summing statement".
        }
        return pow;
    }
```

Result are the same for both :

```
1) 299564530.595318/206587599.027265
---------------------------
2) 299564530.595318/206587599.027265
```